# Chromium based browsers glitch on Debian

Tags: debian, chrome

I've recently switched to Debian 11 and everything's going well so far except I have this weird glitch in every Chromium based browser I've tried, including Chromium itself. So the glitch only happens underneath the bookmark toolbar area. Hiding the toolbar doesn't help. The glitch happens 100% of the time as soon as you start going from page to page. I couldn't detect any sort of pattern but it seems like it's some kind of afterimage. My first thought was it's one of the extensions causing it. I clean installed Chromium though, and it has the same issue. It's just the Chromium browsers. Firefox is working perfectly.

Here are the screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2RhY.jpg

The glitch is mostly static but now and then it'll start flickering as you're moving the mouse.

I have a 3060ti running with the latest drivers. I'm not sure if the problem is with the GPU though. I've googled extensively and found people running into similar issues but not quite the same as this one. In their cases it helped to either switch off hardware acceleration in the browser or playing with the flags. None of that helped me. Any idea what causes this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've actually figured it out. There was an issue with a custom GTK theme I had installed. I changed it and the glitches and flickering are gone.